# How/where to store settings in windows mobile app?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, settings

How / where do I store settings in a windows mobile 6 application (targeting compact framework 3.5)?

Is there some mechanism like the properties.settings for desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just store the stuff in the registry, which is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the System.Configuration is missing from .NET Compact Framework.

You can use the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) or you can just create a class that stores your settings and the save it and load it using a [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use the config settings class to do the job for you. Alternatively, for more flexibility, use an INI class handler (there are a good few out there, look for Windows mobile platform portability). [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) would be your best bet! Hope this helps, Best regards,
 Tom.

Comment: There is a config settings class? Great!
Where can I find it? Or documentation about it?

Comment: I have included the link in the above, http://nini.sourceforge.net. If you have difficulty, let me know and I will gladly email you the source distribution.